# Métodos get y set

Tags: java, clase, metodología

Estoy aprendiendo el uso del `set` , `get` , métodos, clases, etc. Tengo el siguiente código, muy sencillo, pero me da error al ejecutar. Son dos clases, `clase1` y `clase2` .

Los códigos son:

`clase1`

```java
package paquete1;

import java.util.*;

public class clase1 {

    private int edad;
    clase1 obj1 = new clase1();

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }
    
    public int getEdad(){
        return edad;
    }
}
```

`clase2`:

```java
package paquete1;

public class clase2 {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        clase1 obj2 = new clase1();
        
        obj2.setEdad(10);
        System.out.println("La edad es: "+obj2.getEdad());
    }
}
```

Al ejecutar en lugar de decirme que la edad es 10 me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por qué `clase1` tiene una variable `clase1 obj1 = new clase1();`??? Eso no tiene sentido, pues estás obligando a que cada objeto `clase1` tenga dentro un objeto `clase1` que va a tener dentro un objeto `clase1` que va a tener dentro un objeto `clase1` que va a tener dentro un objeto `clase1` que va a tener dentro un objeto `clase1` que va a tener dentro un objeto `clase1` que va a tener dentro un objeto `clase1` que va a tener dentro un objeto `clase1` que va a tener dentro un objeto `clase1` que va a tener dentro un objeto `clase1` que va a tener dentro un objeto `clase1` ... y así :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Estás cayendo en una recursividad sin caso base, tu código se puede traducir a:

> para crear una instancia de `clase1`, necesitas crear primero una instancia de `clase1`.

Esto crea una cadena infinita de creaciones de instancias que acaban consumiendo toda la memoria de la pila (stack) disponible, provocando una sobrecarga (overflow).

Elimina esa línea y todo te funcionará:

```
//Los nombres de las clases empiezan por mayúsculas (convención, no es 
// obligatorio pero sí recomendable).
public class Clase1 {

    private int edad;

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }
    
    public int getEdad(){
        return edad;
    }
}
```

Comment: _Para entender la recursividad necesitas antes entender la recursividad_ ;-)